# How to check a box in a Vuejs nested conditional statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have three objects returned from an `api`. Roles, Products and Permissions. I want to mark checkboxes as checked if a user has permission to perform roles on a product.

The roles table has columns

`id | name | slug`

The permissions table has columns

`id | role_id | user_id | product_id`

The product table has columns

`id | name`

What I have tried

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h4 class="float-left" > <i class="fas fa-cogs text-info" ></i> Permission </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12" v-for="product in products" :key="product.data.product_id">
                <h5 class="mb-4 text-uppercase bg-dark text-white p-2"><i class="mdi mdi-folder me-1"></i> {{product.data.name}}</h5>
                <form> 
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr> 
                                <td v-for="role in roles" :key="role.data.role_id">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" :value="role.data.role_id" :checked="checkIfExists(role, product)" class="form-check-input" :id="role.data.role_id">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" :for="role.data.role_id">{{role.data.name}}</label>
                                    </div> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <action-btn> Update </action-btn>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'Permission',

    data(){
        return {
            permissions: {},
            products: {},
            roles:{},
        }
    },

    methods:{
        checkIfExists(role, product){
            if( this.permissions.map(permission => permission.data.role_id).includes(role.data.role_id) && this.permissions.map(permission => permission.data.product_id).includes(product.data.product_id) ){
                return true;
            }
        },
        getProducts(){
            //working fine
        },

        getRoles(){
            //working fine
        },

        getPermissions(){
            //working fine
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        this.getProducts()
        this.getRoles()
        this.getPermissions()
    }

}
</script>
```

My current result checks a role that is not present in the permissions if the user has at least a role for the permission.

It is supposed to check if the user has a role on the permissions for a product and check just the box attached to the role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
checkIfExists(role, product){
            if( this.permissions.map(permission => (permission.data.role_id === role.data.role_id && permission.data.product_id === product.data.product_id) ? true : false).includes(true) ){
                return true;
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkIfExists` method should be

```
checkIfExists(role, product) {
      return this.permissions.some(
        (permission) =>
          permission.data.role_id === role.data.role_id &&
          permission.data.product_id === product.data.product_id
      );
    },
```

Here's a [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-liskov-b8h4h?file=/src/App.vue:1484-1714)

Comment: thanks. It's still giving the same result